# Want to check for assertion failure in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am a beginner in JMeter. I want to check for Assertion Failures in my script. I want to continue my transaction for a number of iterations after a single log in attempt, and I want to log out only if an error occurs. For that, I want to check if an error occurred in the script.

Is it possible by comparing assertions in JMeter?
If not, is there are any other way to find that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 3):

Define first indicator(s) that will mark response as erratic (Response Code, keyword, etc.).

Try to use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to handle state of your request (success/failure) depending on indicators above and then use IfController along with pre-defined [JMeterThread.last_sample_ok](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) jmeter's variable - whether or not the last sample was OK - true/false.

Schema will look like below e.g.:

```
ThreadGroup
    LOGIN REQUEST
    ...
    YOUR HTTP REQUEST HERE
        Response Assertion
        Response Field to Test: Response Code
        Pattern Matching Rules: NOT Equals
        Patterns to Test: 200
        Regex Extractor
    IfController
    Condition: ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}   // will be TRUE if Response Assertion above is TRUE (i.e. response code != 200)
        LOGOUT REQUEST
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer above I would recommend you:

- Add error checking to your script - assertions that the responses are
  valid for a given reques
- Use Firebug to view network traffic when you need to debug your test
  script
- Use a regular expression extractor to retrieve a dynamic value from a
  response and re-use it in a later request

To get the idea you can follow [JMeter error checking](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/207652-jmeter-video-tutorial-error-checking-and-dynamic-)  video tutorial.

FYI: [Assertion details](http://www.jajakarta.org/jmeter/1.7/en/user_manual/assertions.html) provided.
Hope this helps.